# Nilpotent Quotient Algorithm

Tags: group-presentation, computational-algebra

Does anyone recommend me any reference on the 'Nilpotent quotient algorithm' another book other than D. Johnson "Presentation of groups"? I think that Johnson's example is a bit confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some suggestions, in no particular order. Note that in some cases the material covers in detail the “p-quotient algorithm” as opposed to the nilpotent quotient algorithm. I have found that when speaking to people, sometimes when one refers to one they really mean the other.

[Handbook of Computational Group Theory](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Handbook_of_Computational_Group_Theory.html?id=i2UjAASZ33YC&redir_esc=y)
Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications.
Authors Derek F. Holt, Bettina Eick, Eamonn A. O'Brien. 
Chapter 9 is “Computing quotients of finitely presented groups”. There is also a section in Chapter 12 on Verifying Nilpotency.
On page 364 the authors give a list of references which includes the book of Sims, mentioned below.

For some online lecture notes about the p-quotient algorithm, which are based on the above book, check out: these [notes of Heiko Dietrich.](http://users.monash.edu/~heikod/icts2016/)

A very comprehensive book you could try is “[Computations with finitely presented groups”](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Computation_with_Finitely_Presented_Grou.html?id=k6joymrqQqMC&redir_esc=y) by Charles Sims. In particular Chapter 11. If what you really want is the nilpotent quotient algorithm and not the p-quotient algorithm, maybe the coverage here is most detailed.

You can also explore an implementation of the algorithm using the “[NQ](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/nq.html)” package in GAP. Perhaps computing some examples by hand and checking the result in GAP might be helpful. The [manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/nq-2.5.4/doc/manual.pdf#page8) to the NQ package may also help explain some of the background.